# How to override options set by ftplugins in vim

Tags: vim

I want to be able to set my own `formatoptions` for all filetypes, but I can't seem to get it to override Vim's default *"ftplugins"*.

I put my custom formatoptions in `.vim/after/overrides`, but that doesn't seem to override anything.

If I run `:verbose set formatoptions?` it tells me that the last file to set that option was `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/vim.vim`.

The contents of `.vim/after/overrides.vim` is:

```
" Format Options
set formatoptions=crnj
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The *after* directory tree has the same structure as the one under `~/.vim/`; your `.vim/after/overrides.vim` will never be sourced (check with `:scriptnames`).

You can't generically override *all* filetype plugins with the *after* directory, only individually, e.g. for Vimscript in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim`.

You could do that generic override with an `:autocmd Filetype * setlocal formatoptions=...`, but that would have to be defined *after* the default filetype detection (i.e. `:filetype plugin on`).

You should use `:setlocal` instead of `:set`, just like in the ftplugins.

Comment: Is there an "after" tree for system wide configuration in `/etc` as well? Is this supported by vim?

Comment: @RegisMay That depends on the Vim configuration done by the Linux distribution. You can check `:set rtp?` for a `/etc/.../after` value. Assuming you have write access to the `/etc` tree, you can easily add `:set rtp+=/etc/vim/after` to `/etc/vimrc`