# In which order does VIM load which configuration file?

Tags: vim, configuration-files

I just found some stackoverflow answers to questions regarding VIM and was very much confused why configuration parameters I set did not work as recommended in these answers. It turned out that they simply got overwritten but other VIM configuration files I was not aware of! So I'm wondering:

a) In which order does VIM load which configuration file? (If I learn about this I will likely be able to address the next question.)

b) I want to load all defaults and *then* enable/disable specifically some few settings. In which configuration file do I have to define this?

Please have in mind that I am trying to avoid wild hacking in the configuration files. The next system update will likely overwrite them. Therefor I'm trying to find a way of how to make use of `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` or similar configuration files in order to overwrite all existing settings. But this is of no use if other configuration files are loaded *after* `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` has been loaded. In order to achieve this I attempted to load `/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim` explicitly within `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` and then set `g:skip_defaults_vim` to `1` explicitly to avoid VIM to load it again at a later time. Which - as I can see - does not work as my own settings from `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` get overwritten. But if I load `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` explicitly from within a running VIM instance my settings don't get overwritten. Which I find quite confusing. Does anyone have an idea about that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: have a look at `:scriptnames`. It will show you the load order

Comment: Fantastic! That's the best info s.o. could give me. Thanks! And it clearly shows that all plugins are loaded *after* - not while - the main configuration file is loaded. Now it's perfectly clear why my settings get overwritten.

Comment: if this is your problem, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375119/override-options-set-by-ftplugins-in-vim

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 5):

1. `$ mkdir ~/.vim` and add any custom or third-party scripts to that directory, creating subdirectories as needed.
2. `$ touch ~/.vim/vimrc` and set your options and mappings and whatnot in that file.
3. **Don't do anything vim-related outside of that directory.**
4. Everything is explained in detail in `:help startup`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'd like to avoid: I would like to have a reasonable system default without the need of creating local overrides for very user on each system :-/

Comment: How about letting your users decide what's reasonable or not?

Comment: Why don't you let me as a system administrator decide that? I am very much in doubt that any user will like to find it helpful if spaces are mixed with tabs when editing python files. Neither me nor any of my colleges.

Comment: As a system administrator you should know that the defaults *you* consider "reasonable" are going to piss your users off in one way or another. And that they are going to change them anyway so why bother?

Comment: Yeah, I'm very sure that the users like to mix in spaces where tab indent is required. Sure. Especially as I know every one of them. And the general editing policy.

Comment: Actually it is not uncommon to have things like that in vim. I've read a few of those questions here on SO where people convert all tabs to whitespaces on opening f.e. a python file, and change it back before saving. Vim is perfectly capable of that, which allows everybody to work with what they like, without messing with the policy or other users.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was able to track down the problem and solve it.

I guess it's a bit more complex but basically that's what's going on in Debian based systems:

- First `/etc/vim/vimrc` seems to be loaded. The directory `/etc/vim` seems to be symlinked from `/usr/share/vim/vim80`.
- Within v/etc/vim/vimrc`a file named`debian.vim` is loaded.
- Then within `/etc/vim/vimrc` the file `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` is loaded. That's where I want to make my changes it is intended to be the place for that.
- In this file I source `/usr/share/vim/vim80/defaults.vim` to load the defaults provided by the package maintainer. Then I set `g:skip_defaults_vim` to `1` to prevent vim to load these defaults later again.
- After this within `/usr/vim/vimrc.local` I set all system wide defaults.

If I now run vim some of the defaults aren't in effect. I can explicitly set them within vim to enable them. Or - strangely - not load `defaults.vim`. Within "defaults.vim" the file type indentation plugin is loaded which causes undesired behavior I don't manage to overwrite within `/usr/vim/vimrc.local` . If I turn off this plugin any defauls made are in effect as expected. It seems that this plugin overrides defaults set if specific files are going to be edited *after* all other configurations are accepted by vim already.

So there is a simple solution: Turn off this plugin by adding this line to `/etc/vim/vimrc.local`:

`filetype plugin indent off`

A better approach would be to reconfigure the plugin of course, but for simplicity I won't go that far for now.