# How to override default indentation in Vim

Tags: vim, python-3.6

It seems to be very simple. Just create custom .vimrc file in /home folder, and paste something like:

```
filetype plugin indent on
" show existing tab with 4 spaces width
set tabstop=4
" when indenting with '>', use 4 spaces width
set shiftwidth=4
" On pressing tab, insert 4 spaces
set expandtab
```

But there's still a problem. Pressing ENTER key after a bracket, I still have 8 spaces instead of desired 4. At the same time tab key gives me 4 spaces.

I also found a default vimrc file located in /etc/vim. There is a script:

```
" Uncomment the following to have Vim load indentation rules and plugins
" according to the detected filetype.
"if has("autocmd")
"  filetype plugin indent on
"endif
```

According that if I uncomment these lines I'll eventually get desired four spaces, but I just can't save this because it's "readonly".

I use the "Huge version without GUI" version 8.0 which should support python3 out of the box. I really can't find out how to bypass such minor obstacle. I've killed whole day trying to fix it. Maybe I as a beginner chose wrong text editor? But I like Vim because of its minimalism and I want to have access to its power when I master my skills. At the same time I need a tool for work - now. And incorrect indentation is a small but very annoying snag on my way.

Comment: Try setting the first line in your .vimrc to off . Using your settings on an existing file with indent on  I get 4 spaces per indent after re-indenting. New files should auto indent to 4 spaces

Comment: use `:verbose set ts?` to see where your setting gets overwritten. It has to be a plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override options set by ftplugins in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28375119/override-options-set-by-ftplugins-in-vim)